# Type of function pointer that receives and returns function pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

The type of pointer to `int f(int i) { return i; }` is `int (*)(int)` - this is fine. Also, if I set `using f_ptr = int (*)(int)`, i.e. `f_ptr` is the type of pointer to `f()`, the type of pointer to `f_ptr g(f_ptr fp) { return fp; }` is natually `f_ptr (*)(f_ptr)` - this is also fine.

If so, I feel that `f_ptr (*)(f_ptr)` without `using` should be `int (*)(int) (*[variable comes here])(int (*)(int))` because, well, you get this when you simply replace `f_ptr` by `int (*)(int)` as it's so defined with `using`, but this in fact just causes syntax error. The actual type is `int (*(*[variable comes here])(int (*)(int)))(int)` but I don't get how it becomes this.

It seems that my understanding is fundamentally wrong. Can anybody give me an explanation or a good (hopefully not so in-depth...) resource to understand this?

A snippet might be better than words:

```
int f(int i) {
  return i;
}

using f_ptr = int (*)(int);

f_ptr g(f_ptr fp) {
  return fp;
}

int main() {
  // This makes sense.
  f_ptr (*gp0)(f_ptr) = &g;

  // This is correct, although I don't get it...
  int (*(*gp1)(int (*)(int)))(int) = &g;

  // If you simply replace `f_ptr` by `int (*)(int)` as it's so defined with `using`,
  // I feel the type should become like this, which causes syntax error.
  // int (*)(int) (*gp2)(int (*)(int)) = &g;
}
```

Comment: Your version doesn't work for the same reason that you can't declare a function pointer as `int (*)(int) ptr;`.

Comment: Side note: third version `auto gp2 = &g;`

Comment: "_but this in fact just causes syntax error._" What error? Please [edit] to quote it in full. It might turn out to be illustrative.

Comment: @mch Thanks. I know auto, but I want to understand how c[++] type works...

Comment: Btw. If you afraid the nested function pointer types, there is nothing wrong with `typedef`s or `using`s. The readers will be thankful for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does it this way for compatibility with C

C does it this way so that definitions mirror uses

```
int f(int i) {
  return i;
}

using f_ptr = int (*)(int);

f_ptr g(f_ptr fp) {
  return fp;
}

int main() {
  // Definition
  int (*fp0)(int) = &f;
  // Use
  int m = (*fp0)(1);

  // Definition
  int (*(*gp1)(int (*)(int)))(int) = &g;
  // Use
  int i = (*(*gp1)(fp0))(1);
}
```

Except that the `*`s in the use are optional, so everyone writes

```
  int n = fp0(1);
  int j = gp1(fp0)(1);
```